# Intellij doesn't report that a local variable is accessed from within inner class and needs to be declared final

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I'm using intellij on OSX to write android apps. I've noticed that my intellij stopped reporting that a local variable is accessed from within inner class and needs to be declared final. This means that I don't see the red marker and only when I compile the app I get the error message from gradle.

Picture from intellij

[image]

userId should have red marker, like this

[image]

Error message:

[image]

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you changed "Language level" in Intellij or somewhere in Gradle files? Intellij probably thinks that files are for Java8, where "effective final", without keyword, is good enough.

Comment: Well, in my gradle file the source and target compatibility is JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6 but I've changed it to 8 and then back to 6 and now it's working. So I'm 100% sure your answer is correct. Thanks!